# ASP.NET MVC: Html Helper Form Seems to be Incorrect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

all, I could use your help again. I'm currently attempting to use an HTML helper to create a from that will pass my model into the `Operations` controller's method, `TaskEdit`, seen below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TaskEdit(TaskViewModel viewModel, bool? embedded)
{
    // code
}
```

In the view, I am using the following Razor code to attempt to produce the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TaskEdit", "Operations", new { embedded = true, viewModel = Model }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal"  }))
{
    // form code
}
```

This didn't actually give me my instance of the model - it only passed the class back as if it were a static class. So I tried the following instead:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TaskEdit", "Operations", new { embedded = true, id = Model.TaskId }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal"  }))
{
    // form code
}
```

And the following form was produced (which confused me):

```
<form action="/<sitename>/Operations/TaskEdit/0?embedded=True" class="form-horizontal" method="post"> <!-- Form code --> </form>
```

Not only was I assuming that the form action would be more along the lines of `"/<sitename>/Operations/TaskEdit?id=0&embedded=True"`, but when I try to submit the form, I get a server error about "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." Help?

Comment: you get `/TaskEdit/0` because that's how your routing is setup. In your route configuration you'll notice that there is a parameter `id` that will automatically route any `id` to that format. Can't you just strongly type your view (put the model at the top of the file) and leave out the model in your form call?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Are you saying that I should make my Model an instance variable for my controller?

Comment: No, you should put it at the top of your view (`@model TaskViewModel`) and remove the parameter to your model from your form (`@using (Html.BeginForm("TaskEdit", "Operations", new { embedded = true}, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal"  }))`). Now build up your form using the model (`@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeField)`) and when you submit it, the parameter in your controller (`TaskViewModel viewModel`) will automatically contain the data from your form.

Comment: Let me know if you fixed it so I can throw it in an answer and we can put this as solved.

Comment: Yup. Looks like that solved it. Thanks much. Throw it in an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transcription from the comments:

The reason the URL results in `/TaskEdit/0` is because of the way your routing is setup. You'll notice the route also defines an `id` which causes it to format it different than expected.

The best solution here is to use a strongly typed view:

1) Put your model on top of the view (`@model TaskViewModel`)

2) Remove the model parameter from your form

3) Use the built-in extensions to create form fields (`Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeField)`) or use the field names if you're doing it manually: `<input type="text" name="SomeField />`

4) The model parameter in your controller's actionresult will now contain the form data